# How to handle reentrancy with StampLocks

Tags: java, concurrency, locking, reentrantreadwritelock

I am converting a code with reentrant locks into stamp locks. The code consists of a scenario where `readlock` is inside the `writelock` as following example.

```
private final ReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

A() {
    lock.writeLock().lock();
    ...
    B();
    ...
}

B () {
   lock.readLock().lock();
   ...
}
```

The stamp locks are not reentrant. Then if I change `readLock()` into `tryOptimisticRead()` and `writeLock()` with `writeLock()` in stamp locks, there may be a deadlock scenario.

Hence, I want to know how to handle this kind of scenarios with stamp locks.

Comment: Sounds really risky. If you have to ask, then you probably shouldn't be getting rid of the safer `ReentrantLock`.

Comment: I agree that you should probably stay with the ordinary reentrant lock. Besides that, the solution is very simple: separate code dealing with the locks and the (private) code dealing with the data. The latter must be invoked by the former when holding the appropriate locks.